# how to display the last element in ngx-slick-carousel

Tags: angular

here is my code:

```
<ngx-slick-carousel #slickModal="slick-carousel" [config]="slideConfig">
```

```
slideConfig = {
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    infinite: false,
};
```

what do I need to do in config so it will always display the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it doesn't provide any api to select any index but you can get the template reference and call the `slickGoTo` public [method](https://github.com/leo6104/ngx-slick-carousel/blob/master/src/slick.component.ts#L171) exposed by the `ngx-slick-carousel`.

```
  @ViewChild('slickModal')
  slickModal: SlickCarouselComponent;
```

and on init call the method with the last index to move it:

```
this.slickModal.slickGoTo(lastIndex)
```